# Failed to restart elasticsearch

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch version 2.3.3 installed on a vm with ubuntu version 14.04. I have tried to restart the elasticsearch service but after the restart I checked the status with `sudo service elasticsearch status` and it returned `* elasticsearch is not running`. When I try to start it using `sudo service elasticsearch start` it returns `* Starting Elasticsearch Server` but checking the status it turns out to be not running.

I have tried to manually start it by entering `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch` (which is the path of the binary file) but at the beginning I was getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchException[Failed to load logging configuration]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/config];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:97)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1686)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:109)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:69)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2602)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

The error tells it is not able to find the logging configuration so I followed the advice in https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch/issues/58 by creating a symbolic link:
`sudo ln -s /etc/elasticsearch/ /usr/share/elasticsearch/config`

Afterwards I'm getting the following error when running elastic search through `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`:

```
Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchException[Failed to load logging configuration]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/config];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:426)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:413)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:179)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:69)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2602)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

When trying as root (`sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: don't run elasticsearch as root.
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

This is not the first time I face this issue. I faced exactly the same problem (with the first exception - logging config not found) on another virtual machine and tried to solve it by creating the path `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config` and copying the config files (elasticsearch.yml and logging.yml) to it. Afterwards I faced the second problem again (running as normal user - access denied and running as root is not allowed).

Does anybody have an idea about this problem? Any help will be appretiated!

Comment: Thanks but this is the same link I have refered to in the problem description

Comment: Looks like the user that is running elasticsearch does not have access to the files in `/etc/elasticsearch`. Elasticsearch is usually running as the `elasticsearch` user. So maybe try `chown -R elasticsearch. /etc/elasticsearch/*`

Comment: please attach output id command and does "cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config" work without errors?

Comment: Thanks for helping! I have tried to resolve the issue by following the error messages step by step so I edited the access rights for the config dir, then for elasticsearch.yml and for the patterns dir. Afterwards I had to create a nother sym link to the data dir but all that didn't help (at that level it took forever to start the service without any output) so I simply reinstalled elasticsearch. Luckily enough no data was deleted!

Comment: Now after restarting the node because of installing the delete-by-query plugin elastisearch does not start. Typing `chown -R elasticsearch. /etc/elasticsearch/*` as root gives `chown: cannot access ‘/etc/elasticsearch/*’: No such file or directory` although the directory can be found by `ls` (only accessible for root). `cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config` does not work since the config directory does not exist (that's why I created the sym link but I have deleted it afterwards).

Answer (score 4):

In my case the following link helped :

```
ln -s /etc/elasticsearch/ /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do the following:

1) Create the directories

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts
```

2) Copying over log and config files

```
$ cp /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml /user/share/elasticshare/config
$ cp /etc/elasticsearch/logging.yml /user/share/elasticshare/config
```

3) Change permissions or change ownership on these files.

```
$ sudo chmod g+rwx /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/logging.yml 
$ sudo chmod o+rwx /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/logging.yml
```

Comment: I have previously tried something similar through the sym links (which I suppose have similar effect). Now I'm getting new errors as follows:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log (Permission denied)`
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch_deprecation.log (Permission denied)`
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log (Permission denied)`
and two further similar errors. Unfortunately I can't upload the complete log in comment. Should I change ownership?

Comment: Following are the remaining 2 logs:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log (Permission denied)`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)`
These are only the first line of each error

Comment: Now after changing the ownership I'm only getting the last error:
`log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log] to [/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch.log.2016-09-01].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data)
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data`
Should I create a folder /usr/share/elasticsearch/data and move the contents of /var/lib/elasticsearch/ into it?

Comment: Yes, first make sure the data directory configured in elasticsearch.yml is the same '/var/lib/elasticsearch/data'. Also, have you tried running the service without sudo from the elasticsearch user?

Comment: After moving the content to the data directory I got the following error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load plugin descriptor for existing plugin [plugin-descriptor.properties]. Was the plugin built before 2.0?
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/plugin-descriptor.properties/plugin-descriptor.properties: Not a directory
` so I removed the delete-by-query plugin and afterwards starting elasticsearch gives only some INFO and WARN messages but no errors and it doesn't work though.

Comment: Did you check the logs for any errors and are you able to check the cluster status using the REST APIs?

Comment: In /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log I only found logs from yesterday. While the other files in the folder are all empty. Is there another  path to check for log files?
Anyway I assume it's a problem with the delete-by-query plugin since it worked fine before installing that plugin.

Comment: giving all access using chmod to both group and owner, did fix my issue.
I.e to 
`sudo chmod -R o+rwx data`
`sudo chmod -R o+rwx logs`